Temporary directories left behind by the CreateArchive function
The CreateArchive function sometimes leaves empty subdirectories of the form m_x in the destination directory, where x is a ten-digit alphanumeric identifier that looks to be unique. This behavior was observed on WL versions 12 through 14 under Windows 7 through 11; no experience with MacOS and Linux. Similar remnants are left after CreatePacletArchive and PacletBuild that make use of CreateArchive. While it's easy to write a function to safely delete those subdirectories, what's the reason they're left behind when they're of no use?
